# Can you deploy your Azure Web App via GitHub if you're not the repo owner?

Tags: git, azure, github, deployment, azure-web-app-service

Let's say you have a web application that you've pushed to GitHub. You can deploy it as an Azure Web App (formerly Azure Web Site) by entering your GitHub credentials into your Deployment settings on the Azure portal.

But how about GitHub repositories that you contribute to, but don't have ownership of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a mentor at hackathon events, I've had students come up to me and ask me the above question, because another member of their team owns the repository. When they linked their GitHub account to their Azure account, they could only see their own GitHub projects.

The solution is to have the owner of the GitHub repo use their Azure account to enter the deployment credentials to set up continuous deployment.

If you contribute to that GitHub repo, all future pushes will automatically deploy the latest code to the Azure Web App on the live website URL.

Comment: p.s. good suggestion from Cory Fowler: create an org account instead, so that the GitHub account isn't tied to 1 person. This works well for new projects and long-term projects, and can also work for existing projects that can be migrated. For a weekend hackathon with an existing project, using the existing GitHub project owned by 1 person may suffice.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest creating a Github Organization for the Hackathon group and adding each GitHub user to the Organization. That way everyone that has access to that organization is able to access the code and each of them can have their own deployment of the site.

Here is a video on the new [GitHub workflow](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Azure-Web-Sites-Tutorials/Github-Continuous-Delivery-in-the-Preview-Portal) in the Preview Portal

Comment: Here is a blog post that explains how to enable access to organizations for GitHub in the Azure Portal. http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/08/10/using-app-service-web-apps-continuous-deployment-with-github-organizations/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest forking that repo and then publishing from your fork.

Comment: You're right, forking the code is a good strategy for the development process and being able to test individual contributions of code. I do still suggest providing access to the organization so that everyone has the ability to get the current "production version" as not everyone typically works by using feature branches especially in a hackathon setting.